# switching to a specific window

Tags: c, gtk, xlib

I'm writing a program using XLIB and gtk, I'm supposed to implement a function to switch a specific window(using any human identifyable reference, window name, process name or anything that is going to be static everytime that application is run)

I'm completely lost and I cannot find anything to guide me through the beginning of the application

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with X libraries but it'll be a bit of a pain: you'll have to understand X IPC and properties. Fortunately there's an easier way, assuming you can use other libraries: use [Libwnck](https://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/). Here's a minimal example to list windows (adapted from the "Getting started" page):

```
WnckScreen *screen = wnck_screen_get_default ();
WnckWindow *active_window = wnck_screen_get_active_window (screen);
GList *l;

for (l = wnck_screen_get_windows (screen); l != NULL; l = window_l->next) {
    WnckWindow *window = WNCK_WINDOW (window_l->data);
    g_print ("%s%s\n", wnck_window_get_name (window),
                       window == active_window ? " (active)" : "");
}
```

Switching to a specific window should be just:

```
wnck_window_activate (window, 0);
```

The only gotcha is that wnck is designed to be used with a GLib mainloop. If you are not running one (as would be the case for a simple command line app), you'll need to use `wnck_screen_force_update ()` to fetch the current data from X (see the "Getting started" example).

Comment: unfortunately, libwnck is not available on the OS I'm developing for, I'm willing to learn Xlib IPC if you can point me in the right direction

Comment: Building libwnck only depends on gtk/x11. (And every mainstream distro certainly packages it)